# Problem with customized android build

Tags: android, porting

I'm trying to make a customized build (as described in the porting guide - http://source.android.com/porting/build_new_device.html) and always end up with the error message
make: *** No rule to make target `vendor/company/emh-board/kernel', needed by`out/target/product/emh-board/kernel'. Stop.

Does anyone know why this is happening. I start build using the "make PRODUCT-emh-user"
My AndroidBoard.mk looks like

```
# make file for new hardware  from 
#
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
#
# this is here to use the pre-built kernel
ifeq ($(TARGET_PREBUILT_KERNEL),)
TARGET_PREBUILT_KERNEL := $(LOCAL_PATH)/kernel
endif
#

file := $(INSTALLED_KERNEL_TARGET)
ALL_PREBUILT += $(file)
$(file) : $(TARGET_PREBUILT_KERNEL) | $(ACP)
        $(transform-prebuilt-to-target)

#
# no boot loader, so we don't need any of that stuff..  
#
LOCAL_PATH := vendor/company/emh-board
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
#
# include more board specific stuff here? Such as Audio parameters.     
#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have managed to find out the answer... After looking deeper into the build procedure I figured out that I either needed to place the kernel in the product/kernel folder, or provide a prebuilt kernel via TARGET_PREBUILT_KERNEL variable. I hope this saves somebody some time if going through that procedure described in the porting guide.